# Is wiring supplying an integrated HVAC breaker a branch circuit or feeder?

Tags: electrical, hvac, circuit-breaker, furnace, wire

Since this air handler / furnace has overcurrent protective devices in it, would my wiring from the panel then be a feeder or branch circuit?

[image]

I kind of think it would be a feeder circuit. And that would mean I have to obey feeder rules. But since this is part of the unit, I'm not sure.

Comment: This air-handler uses electric heating elements (strip heat) I take it?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have breakers there it would be a feeder. A branch circuit : the conductors between the final overcurrent device protecting the circuit and outlets. In article 100 definitions see exhibit 100.7 commentary is the direction from the feeder definition.

Comment: A question for educational purposes (my education mostly!):  What is the effective difference between a feeder and a branch circuit in these circumstances?   Is it bc the receiving device has overcurrent protection? As in if the furnace has a breaker, the cable is a feeder, but if it doesn't it's a branch circuit?

Comment: @george Anderson, that is basically it the definition of a feeder is not as clear but points to the branch circuit definition and examples exhibit 100.7 of the code book. Branch circuits go to the devices where a feeder goes to a  branch circuit overcurrent current Device. Like a sub or in this case the multiple breakers for electric heat.